# Method 'VBE' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: vba, excel, vbe, vbide

One of my clients has issue running the Excel VBA code below. He gets the following error `Method 'VBE' of object '_Application' failed`, but only once, after he opens the VBE, it starts to work. Also, it was working for him until yesterday.

He is using Excel 2010.

This is the code that throws the error.

```
For Each f In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    If InStr(1, f.Name, "UserForm") = 1 Then
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove (f)
    End If
Next f
```

Comment: Sounds like permissions setting. What Trust Center Macro Settings he has? Excel: File -> Options, Trust Center. Trust Center -> Macro Settings. Is the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" ticked?

Comment: What have you actually tried yourself to identify the problem? You need to show your research effort.

Comment: It's best not to delete things from a collection while you're looping over that collection.  Add the items to an array or a new collection and then delete them when you're done with the initial loop.

Comment: Using unnecessary parentheses can also cause issues - it should be `.Remove f` instead of `.Remove (f)`

Comment: @PatricK I checked that first thing. It's there.

Comment: @Macro Man Well, i search for similar problems, usually it was a problem in the Trust settings OR .ThisWorkbook, had to be after Application, but that doesnt work for this case.

Comment: @barrowc Thanks, will try. But funny thing is, that it was working for like 6 months. Must be the settings somewhere.

Comment: @TimWilliams OK, will refactor that part.

Comment: And also, its only problem at his PC, when i run that on my PC everything is OK.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enure that Access to the VBE is trusted, by navigating to the Trust Center in Excel Options.

Some actions on the VBComponents require that the VBE has been opened at least once, or at least, that the VBA has referenced the VBE *before* it tries to enumerate the vbComponents.

It looks like your client's code might be running in an `auto_open` procedure or `Workbook_Open` event. You may find that the code begins to work again if you explicitly add a line the refers to the VBE *before* you enumerate the vbComponents.

```
Debug.Assert Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name <> vbNullString

For Each f In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    If InStr(1, f.Name, "UserForm") = 1 Then
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Remove (f)
    End If
Next f
```

See the details in the answers on this question:
[VBA changing sheet codename Run-Time Error 9: Subscript out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022319/vba-changing-sheet-codename-run-time-error-9-subscript-out-of-range)

Answer (score 1):

the `Debug.Assert ...` mentioned by [@ThunderFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41292488/1915920) did not work for me, but the **Trust Center Options** did: (depending on your Excel version something like):

```
Excel  ->  Menu  ->  File
->  Options
    ->  Trust Center
        ->  Macro Settings
            ->  Developer Macro Settings
                ->  [x] Trust access to the VBA project object model
```

A general approach to solve such *VBComponent*-dependent code problems is to use the **[`VbeInit` procedure given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726959/1915920)** that is flexible to be called multiple times for each newly opened workbook that may not yet be "*VBComponent*-initialized".

Comment: Currently I can reproduce the problem if I open Excel (2010) and the `Workbook_Open` event is accessing the VBComponents, although Trust Center settings are ok. It is working in Excel 2016 though :-/

Comment: Since I only wanted to (generically) access the `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("MyModule").ActiveVBComponent.FileName` I replaced it by calling `MyWorkbook.FullName` for Excel 2010 support.