# Excel VBA: Method 'Wait' of object '_Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba, wait

I am using same Splash Screen User Form for 3 years in my company but today it started giving `Method 'Wait' of object '_Application' failed` error.
I am assuming this is related to New Microsoft Share Point (previously we were using our internal share point now using cloud)

I tried to search on SO but nothing exactly same. (i.e: [Method 'VBE' of object '_Application' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143670/method-vbe-of-object-application-failed))

I tried deleting the extra paranthesis but no change...

I am thinking of adding `On Error` statement but if my splash screen won't pop-up why would I have this code & user form? So honestly rather than `On Error` statement I want to have a real solution.

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
SplashUserForm.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
SplashUserForm.Repaint
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Unload SplashUserForm
Application.OnKey "{F7}", "showContains"
```

*An Error comes straight away when it comes to `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))`

> UPDATE

After reviewing [Stax' suggestion as per his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957565/there-is-no-wait-method-associated-with-application-in-visualbasic-word?answertab=votes#tab-top) once I change the `Application` object with `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` this fixes the first problem which is `Wait` method. But then the next line `OnKey` method doesn't work with `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Comment: When/where is this code invoked from?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I call my user form through ThisWorkBook. Whenever anyone opens the workbook, splash screen welcomes users.

Comment: See if [late binding helps??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957565/there-is-no-wait-method-associated-with-application-in-visualbasic-word?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @Stax but you want the *current* `Application` instance to sleep/wait, not some ad-hoc late-bound instance. Win32 `Sleep` isn't a bad idea though.

Comment: Another idea could be to make the workbook open on a "splash sheet" with developer/support contact info. Without gridlines, row/column headings, and no formula bar, it's just as good a blank canvas as anything else... and then you can keep it around if you want, or hide it as soon as any other sheet is activated.

Comment: I tried `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` rather than `Application` , it worked but rather than 1 second it takes 3-5 second for each step to load.
+ After this line, it gave me an error on this last line: `Application.OnKey "{F7}", "showContains"` After changing this Application with CreateObject, yes doesn't give an error but doesn't work as well.

Comment: `Sleep` should do what you want.

Comment: I couldn't manage to combine `Private Sub UserForm_Activate` and `Private Declare Sub Sleep`. When I try to write underneath of the main sub it gives me this compile error: `"Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property"`
Also another problem with `Sleep`, After `Application.Wait`, I have `Application.OnKey` - even if I work it out `Sleep`,how to solve last step?

Comment: Potentially try a delay function instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389093/delay-macro-to-allow-events-to-finish

Comment: @Tragamor I understood that the problem is not related to `Wait` method rather it's related to `Application` object. @Stax' link has given me `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` way of doing it which gradually solves the problem. (For example it fixes it on the `Wait` method. But doesn't work on the `OnKey`method.

Comment: Mathieu... Yes, I have only seen it in a colleagues code, and only recalled what you point out when you did. Duh!. :-). Grasping at straws now.. Tried adding "Excel." before the Application.Wait to fully qualify it?? Try having the userform modeless?? 
`SplashUserForm.Show (0)
SplashUserForm.Label1.Caption = "Opening..."
SplashUserForm.Repaint
Excel.Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.ScreenUpdating=False and it goes quicker.