# The module (VBComponent) that is currently running

Tags: excel, vba

Is there some way to refer to the module (VBComponent) that is currently running.

Something like `Thisworkbook` or `ActiveWorkBook`, but to refer to the code that is running at a given time, like `ActiveVBComponent` or `ThisVBComponent`?

I have searched Google and this page and have not found any information.

Thank you.
Greetings.

Comment: For what purpose? Why do you need it? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm building code that modifies itself. To assign the code I must use:

`Set code = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ConstModuleName).CodeModule`

As the name of the module I must use a constant that I have to define previously (`ConstModuleName`), which forces me to have to modify its value if for any reason I change the name of the module.

I was trying to do this without having to declare a constant with the module name, but rather referring to the name of the module that is executing said code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There is no native object that you can readily refer to in VBA that will give you the name of the module that is currently running. You can't even get the name of the running procedure!

A free workaround that people use is to create a constant at the module level that contains the name of the module.

```vb
Private Const C_MODULE_NAME As String = "MyModule"
```

However this approach needs to be maintained manually and can be error-prone. If you want to automate this process of inserting the constant, you could take inspiration in [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/InsertProcedureNames.aspx) from C. Pearson where he inserts a constant for every procedure.

However, if you only need this information for debugging reasons, there is a paid third-party tool named vbWatchdog that allows you to display the information about the module inside the error dialog window. How does it do it? It's unfortunatly complicated and not really something a regular VBA user can do:

> vbWatchdog injects precompiled code into the memory and uses [it] as [a] classobject. Since the Author knows how to decompile compiled VBA he gets the proc_name and other information from the compiled code.
> ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945321/how-to-get-the-procedure-or-function-name-at-runtime#comment44165741_23960315))

---

Just for completeness, note that there is a property, `VBE.ActiveCodePane`, that you can access and it will give you the active code pane in the VBE, but there is no guarantee that the actively running procedure is located in that code pane. This just happens to be the last code pane that was selected.