How can I have vba identify the current procedure name without using ErrHandler?
I wrote a procedure to create a log of each procedure run. It's added as a calling procedure within the ones being tracked, and we have to add the procedure name as a string passthrough value. I would like either procedure to identify the procedure name, so that we don't have to add it as a passthrough, but I haven't been able to determine how to do that.
I have an unrelated procedure that creates a listing of all modules/procedures currently in the xlam. In that code, it reads the first line of each procedure to identify the name. But it's looping through ALL modules and identifying where one begins and ends using CountOfLines, and I am looking for this to identify a specific one, the active procedure.

There's nothing built-in for this, you will have to handle it manually. Out of curiosity, how would you get the executing procedure name from the error handler?

No offence, but can you explain what "error handler" means for you? I am also curious to understand how you use it to identify the executing procedure...

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945321/how-to-get-the-procedure-or-function-name-at-runtime

The link Bart provided uses err handler, not how I need to use the info

ok thanks Kostas!  Not the answer I was hoping for but i guess it's the answer we get

But you were the one mentioning the "method" of logging the procedure name "using ErrHandler"... Probably, that's why Bart was showing that link. You need to create a procedure able to write in a log file, to be called from each procedure (you need to be logged) appending the text with its name and logging/running time.
